# Excel - Random Numbers - and If statement

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

In "A", rows 1-1000, I generate random numbers using RAND(). I want to pick numbers between say 1-100.

In "B" for 1000 rows I have `=RAND()*(100-1)+1`

In "C" for 1000 rows I use the numbers that I generated in "A", so `=A1*(100-1)+1`

The averages in B and C are the same, as expected.

I only want to use the values for 20% of the time, so for each of the 1000 rows:

For B, I use  `=IF(A1<0.2,B1,0)`
For C, I use  `=IF(A1<0.2,C1,0)`

If I do this, the averages for each of the two columns are vastly different.

**Can anybody explain why?**

Both approaches are using random numbers.  The first approach uses two different random numbers (from column "A" and the one used in the "B" column calculation).

Answer (score 3):

Columns A and B have the same uniform distribution, aside from the linear transformation, but are independant. B's probability density function (PDF) for *A<0,2* is the same as the PDF for any other selection of A.

Columns A and C are not independant. In fact, they are completely deterministic. If you select rows where *A<0,2*, you are only selecting rows where *C<20,8*. The probability of finding a value of C greater than 20,8 within that selection has dropped to zero. Clearly, the distribution has changed.

For a more obvious example of this, consider rolling two dice (A and B) and their total (C). I'd expect to see an average of 3,5 in columns A and B, and an average of 7 in column C. If from this table I only select rows where die A landed on 1, I'd still see an average of 3,5 in B (independant), but merely 4,5 instead of 7 in column C (dependant).

Comment: Thank you very much.  This was driving me crazy.  Your explanation is very clear.

Answer (score 0):

For your 1 in 5 sample from ColumnC, instead of choosing the `C` value based on the `A` value for the corresponding row (ie those `A` values less than 0.2) try choosing your 1 in 5 `C` sample from an adjacent row. Say use `=IF(A1<0.2,C2,0)`. This should give you similar averages for the two columns (though `=A1(100-1)+1` is not correct).

Then you should have a more-or-less representative 1 in 5 of ColumnC rather than merely (approximately) a scaled up version of values preselected to be the bottom 20%.

In other words, your ColumnB ‘vastly different’ (but probably anticipated ie around 50) average is probably about five times the ColumnC sample average. Choose 1 in 10 on the above basis and would be ~10 times.

Rather than scaling up, if you want to generate 1000 approximately random numbers in the range 1-100 then you could apply `=RANDBETWEEN(1,100)`.